# Retrieve the drawables from an animated gif in Android

Tags: java, android, image, animated-gif

I'd like to retrieve the different drawables inside an animated gif programmatically in Android.

Answer (score 0):

Messy, but you aren't going to be able to do that with the standard platform tools. You'll need an animated GIF decoder library to do that on ANY platform. Take a look at http://www.mydigitallife.co.za/index.php?option=com_myblog&show=a-j2me-gif-decoderhtml&Itemid=29: it is somewhat complex but may give you the start you need to extract the individual images.

Alternatively consider doing the image extraction on a remote server.